# Validation errors as an array

Tags: php, codeigniter

Am using codeigniter version (2.1.4). Am asking if the validation library provides a solution to access validation errors as an array instead of validtation_errors() method.

Regards

Comment: Nope If you need to display the error message somewhere. Use variable to start the html section and use it...

Comment: @Nes Your answer is not clear. Please clarify the picture for me !

Comment: There will not return you a array in codeigniter. What purpose you need it as array?

Comment: @Nes for some reason I want to loop through the produced error messages.

Comment: You have option to change the error messages in codeigniter.

Comment: Here my sugesstion: store the validtation_errors() in php variable and use that to display where you want. And use CSS to format the error message. Error message like "<p>Username field required</p>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend the form validation library `CI_Form_validation` define your function `validation_error_array` variable `$this->_error_array` will have the all the errors

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    function validation_error_array()
    {
        return $this->_error_array;
    }
}
```

[**See for reference**](http://darrenonthe.net/2011/05/10/get-codeigniter-form-validation-errors-as-an-array/)

Comment: Ok , the inheritance makes since. But PHP still not supporting multiple inheritance since am extending CI_CONTROLLER as well !

Comment: While when you load form validation library instead load your validation library `MY_Form_validation` and when you call `validation_error_array()` using your library you will have the errors array donot extend your controller to validation library just load your new validation library

Comment: Good tip , lets me do that !
If it is worked I will back to you to approve your answer. Thanks for help !

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it works in your specified version but in the latest version 
you can use

```
$this->form_validation->error_array()
```

and pass that to view or even better post your form as ajax request and get error messages as array back.
You don't need to initialize form helper unless you are using other form elements

Answer (score 1):

You can use the validation_errors() to show all the errors in one place or you can show each error message with respective field in the following way.

```
 <?php echo form_error('username'); ?>
 <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" size="50" />
```

and also you can change the error delimiters.

Global delimiters.

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
```

Individual delimiters.

```
<?php echo form_error('field name', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>

Or:

<?php echo validation_errors('<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
```

So i dont think you should have a need to get validation errors in an array.

Comment: Actullay I like your answer. But the need for the array still needed. I looked to some validation engines and they provide a way to access the errors as an array. This problem is one of the drawbacks of Form Validation in Codeigniter !

Comment: i dont think it as a drawback as its providing both the ways to show the error messages.

Comment: I respect your opinion. But as you know some people wanna to process those messages in some way by looping through the elements. As a developer I think it is very important to provide such facility !